# How to pass action output to TCPDF in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, tcpdf

Hi I am new in zend framework. I am using TCPDF in zend framework. I am facing a problem for printing a content in pdf.

I have write the below code in controller:

```
$html = ob_get_clean();

         $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

            $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $pdf->SetAuthor('Test');
            $pdf->SetTitle('Test');
            $pdf->SetSubject('Test');
            $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

            $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
            $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

            $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

            $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 20, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

            $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(20);

            $pdf->SetFooterMargin(25);

            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

            $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

            $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

            $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 8, '', true);

            $pdf->AddPage();

            $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

            $pdf->writeHTMLCell($w=0, $h=0, $x='', $y='', $html, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);

            $datetime=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

            $pdf->Output('MIS_Report_'.$datetime.'.pdf', 'I');
```

and I have write my content in phtml file in views folder which is to be displays on the pdf.

When I run my code. It will show me the pdf but no content is displayed.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't need layout

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$html = $this->view->render('controllername/actionname.phtml');
```

Comment: I have another problem that when i pass my data into phtml file of pdf from database it gives an erroe "Undefined index: cols in /cmiportal/cm/cmi013/library/tcpdf/tcpdf.php on line 21971"